# How to access mysql database details to enter while setting up the configuration of WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a sub-folder - tapasodisha.org/odisha (Odisha is in Odia language)

Since I'm using the WordPress hosting from Bluehost, I'm unable to access the cPanel. So, I first created an FTP account for tapasodisha.org.

Then, logged in to FileZilla using FTP account details and created the sub-folder there and copied the WordPress files.

WordPress is installed but, I don't know the database name, username, password, database host, table prefix details to proceed further and configure WordPress.

I tried configuring WordPress using FTP account login details but, still not able to configure it.

Please help.

Comment: The only people that would know the authoritiative answer to this question would be [BlueHost support](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help?_ga=2.65411561.699822220.1539184075-659360055.1539184075). That being said: I find it unlikely Bluehost has not granted you access to their Control Panel section, **especially** if you had access to some section where you could create FTP accounts. Was this restriction specifically mentioned in any literature they gave you when you signed up? If so, would you mind citing it?

Comment: With Bluehost WordPress hosting, we can't access the cPanel. That's the biggest disadvantage but yes, we can create FTP accounts. I didn't know this before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that "Bluehost WP hosting"  works, but if you already had a working Wordpress system before (from that auto setup / hosting), you could (via FTP) look for the `wp-config.php` file, which should be in the root folder of that WP installation. In there you'll find `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` for the used database and server.

Comment: I can access the wp-config.php file for the main website and I could find the MySQL details as well for the main website. Here I'm creating a sub-folder. I have explained my query above. Can I get the details of DB_name, DB_username, DB_password for this sub-folder from any third party software? Let me know.

Comment: well, you are planning to use the same database as for the main website if I understood you correctly (?). If yes, those are the data to access it - database access has nothing to do with subfolders and file locations.

Comment: Yes, I have to use the same database since I don't have access to cPanel. How to install WordPress in a subfolder and access it using the same MySQL details? If I use the same details then, I'm logging in to the main folder only, right?

Comment: Whereever you install Worpress, you will also need to have a `wp-config.php` file in the main folder of *that*  installation. You'll have to edit that file and fill in the same data for database access.

Comment: I want to log in to http://example.com/sub-folder. But, if I use the same data from the main folder, does it help? It'll again redirect to http://example.com, right?

Comment: That depends what you define as the URI in the main Worpress settings in the backend - you can use the URI including subfolder there.

Comment: Actually, example.com is for English language and example.com/sub-folder is for one Indian regional language. So, I need to access both. Both should have a separate WordPress login. That's why I need to know MySQL database details. Is there any third party software where I can get these details?